# Linux: How to auto open terminal when a script is run

Tags: linux, bash, xterm

Ok, so I am going to write a script and I need it to auto open xterm when I double-click it (similar to a BAT on Windows). It needs to work on ANY desktop that includes xterm. So for example it would do a check if it was already running in xterm then if not it would reopen itself in xterm and if it is the script will continue its process. Sorry if this has already been asked but I was unable to find anything for the life of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
xterm -e program [ arguments ... ]
```

From the linux man page...

> This option specifies the program (and its command line arguments) to
>   be run in the xterm window. It also sets the window title and icon
>   name to be the basename of the program being executed if neither -T
>   nor -n are given on the command line. This must be the last option on
>   the command line.

Comment: Actually, this does not check and reopen as requested.  There is likely no concise method for doing this, however.

Comment: @ThomasDickey It's ok, I found some other code online to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind that it is possible for other scripts to set environment variables (including those done for the wrong reasons), you can check one of the environment variables set by xterm.  For instance (see [manual](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h2-ENVIRONMENT)):

> **XTERM_VERSION**
>   is set to the string displayed by the **-version**  option.   That  is
>   normally  an  identifier  for the X Window libraries used to build
>   xterm, followed by xterm's patch number in parenthesis.  The patch
>   number  is  also  part  of  the  response  to  a  Secondary Device
>   Attributes (DA) control sequence (see Xterm Control Sequences).

That variable was added in 2005 ([patch #202](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_202)), so it should be available on any system to which you have access.

In a script, you can do this check in one line, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh                                                           
test -z "$XTERM_VERSION" && exec xterm -e $0 $*
view $*
```

This checks if the given variable is set, and if not, it transfers control to xterm passing the information needed to run the script from the start.